# How to convert an object with property and key to Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an object that looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert it into an array and after some researching, I did something like this:

```
Object.keys(langs).map(function (key) { return langs[key]; });
```

and the output looks like this:

[image]

Although it works, that is not what I wanted. What I wanted to do is something like

```
[
    {
        "code": "af",
        "lang": "Afrikaans"
    },
    {
        "code": "am",
        "lang": "Amharic"
    },
    {
        "code": "ar",
        "lang": "Arabic"
    }
]
```

and so forth..

What would be the best way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys(langs).map(function (key) { return { 'code': key, 'lang': langs[key]}; });`

Instead of returning just the value, we return a new object with the attributes code and lang

Comment: Perfect. I will mark this as best answer in a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add code property to your map like so:

```js
var obj = {
  "af" : "Afrikaans",
  "am" : "Amharic",
  "ar" : "Arabic"
}

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(e => ({ code: e, lang: obj[e] }))

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Object#entries` available, you can write this concisely as

```
langs.entries().map(([code, lang]) => ({code, lang}))
```